Does "fractive" have any standard definition?
When creating an SO answer, I stated the undermentioned:

This answer supercedes its predecessive counterpart by supporting any fractive combination.

I included "fractive" in there because I didn't consider that it might not be the adjectival form of fraction until I had written and read it a few times. Even then, I only thought it worth a cursory confirmational search, yet it yielded almost no results – the word doesn't appear to exist in any standard lexicon.
The sole example of its usage is the (manually) bolded term within the undermentioned quotation, extracted from The Blank Slate: The Modern Denial of Human Nature (by Steven Pinker):

In the spirit of Locke, one could attribute these feats to an abstract noun — perhaps not to “the understanding” but to “learning,” “intelligence,” “plasticity,” or “adaptiveness.” But as Leibniz remarked, to do so is to “ [save appearances] by fabricating faculties or occult qualities... and fancying them to be like little demons or imps which can without ado perform whatever is wanted, as though pocket watches told the time by a certain horological faculty without needing wheels, or as though mills crushed grain by a fractive faculty without needing anything in the way of millstones.”

This example was acquired by the sole additional question asking what I am now (at forum.wordreference.com), which cites a now-deleted answer to the same question at Yahoo Answers:

Absolutely nothing, since "fractive" is not a real word.

...(hence it not being indexed by search engines).
Does anyone know of any additional usage examples of this, so that I might know whether it has a standardised usage, even if not the one which I hoped?

fraction, fractional, not fractive. But that quote from Leibniz is a translation. And Pinker failed to catch the oddity. I'd go and find the original, in German. [the quotation mentioned below because under mentioned would mean not mentioned enough...and anyway, undermention is not a word in English]

Maybe he meant: fractious and the translator goofed.

https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/fractive. But also: The meaning of REFRACTIVE is having power to refract. So perhaps: The meaning of FRACTIVE is having power to fract. :)

It's quite common for people to make up an adjective ("fractive") from a noun ("fraction") even if an adjective ("fractional") already exists in common use - even if you'd expect someone to know and use the common adjective, that's not always how people's brains work.

@Lambie, "undermentioned" (not "undermention") is, according to Cambridge Dictionary. Please at least do a cursory search like I did before you purport otherwise. Otherwise, thanks for the context.

I think the intended target word was a non-existent adjectival form of fracture (millstones fracture / crack / grind grains into powdered flour). Maybe fracturing would be better, but it's not really idiomatic. And fracking has a significantly different scope today. But it's nothing to do with "fractions".

(...although you could maybe use fractioning in the context of fractional distillation of moonshine / hooch! :)

Well, I guess I missed that UK formal usage.

I would hope that if you saw the wording 'This answer supercedes its predecessive counterpart by supporting any fractive combination…' as meaningful, you'd be able to rephrase it at least two or three ways. Can you, please?

@RobbieGoodwin, how do you advise I rephrase it, and can you elaborate why?
